# Modal Dropdown List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have created a four part modal dropdown list using Bootstrap 4.

The first two dropdown list execute without any problems, displaying all available values. However, the last two dropdown lists will not execute the dropdown values.

I've provided sample code below, please review code and provide any assistance. Much appreciated.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="test1">Test1:</label>
<select id="test1" name="test1" class="form-control linked-dropdown" data- 
linked="test2">
  <option value="">-- Select Test1 --</option>
  <option value="Test1">Test1</option>
  <option value="Test2">Test2</option>
  </select><p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="test2">Test2:</label>
<select id="test2" name="test2" class="form-control linked-dropdown" data-
linked="test3">
<option value="">-- Select Test2 --</option>    
</select><p>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="test3">Test3:</label>
<select id="test3" name="test3" class="form-control linked-dropdown" data-
linked="test3">
<option value="">-- Select Test3 --</option>    
</select><p>&nbsp;</p>  

<div class="form-group">
<label for="test4">Test4</label>
<select id="test4" name="test4" class="form-control">
<option value="">-- Select Test4--</option>
</select><p>&nbsp;</p>  

<button type="button" class="btn btn-very-light-gray" data-dismiss="modal"  
id="clickButton">Submit</button>
<button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-very-light-gray"  
id="clickButton">Cancel</button></div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div>

<script>
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () { 
location.reload();
});

var dataFirstSelect={
option:[ 'Test1','Test2']
}
var dataSecondSelect={
Test1:['A','B'],
Test2:['E','F']
}
var dataThirdSelect={
Test1:['C','D'],
Test2:['G','H']
}
var dataFourthSelect={
'C’:[{form:'CNN',link:'https://www.cnn.com'}],  
'D’:[{form:'MSNBC',link:'http://www.msnbc.com'},]
}

$('#test1').on('change',function(){
var a=$(this).val();
if(a!==''){       
for(var i=0;i<dataSecondSelect[a].length;i++){
$('#test2').append($("<option></option>")
                                .attr("value",dataSecondSelect[a][i])
                                .text(dataSecondSelect[a][i]));   
}
 }
});

$('#test2').on('change',function(){
var a=$(this).val();
if(a!==''){       
for(var i=0;i<dataThirdSelect[a].length;i++){
$('#test3').append($("<option></option>")
                                .attr("value",dataThirdSelect[a][i])
                                .text(dataThirdSelect[a][i]));   
}
}
});
$('#test3').on('change', function() {
var b = $(this).val();
if (b !== '') {
for (var i = 0; i <dataFourthSelect[b].length; i++) {
$('#test4').append($("<option></option>")
      .attr("value",dataFourthSelect[b][i].link)
      .text(dataFourthSelect[b][i].form));  
}
}
});

function openDoc(url){

window.open   
(url,"_blank","menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,
scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
}

$('#clickButton').on('click',function(){
var data=new Object;
$('select').each(function(){
  //console.log($(this));
data[$(this)["0"].id]=$(this).val();  
});

openDoc(data.form);
});    
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The fourth dropdown list has no options beyond _-- Select Test4 --_. What are you expecting?

Comment: Maybe that's what I'm missing. Can you clarify how I would correct the 4th dropdown?

Comment: Add some options?

Comment: I've revised the code, but it's still not working. I appreciate your review and feedback.

Comment: Can you update the code above? And can you be a little more specific about what "still isn't working?"

Comment: The code above has been updated. As an example if the user selects Test1 from the first dropdown, the second dropdown options are A & B, the third dropdown is where my code stops executing. IF it continued to execute, if the user selected B, the third dropdown options are C & D. If the user selects C & clicks the button, the cnn website displays in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here are a few things I recommend you look into:

Using an IDE that will automatically check syntax (or more robust code editor) such as Visual Studio Code or Sublime when working on a project like this.

VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/

Sublime: https://www.sublimetext.com/

Using the developer tools console, you'll see errors and other useful information.

Chrome developer tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Just a few things to keep in mind for later, I see two issues here that need to be addressed.

There is a syntax error when initializing the `dataFourthSelect` object. It looks like you're using a different style quote to close the keys. Here is the corrected version:

```
var dataFourthSelect = {
    'C' : [{
        form: 'CNN', 
        link: 'https://www.cnn.com'
    }],
    'D' : [{ 
        form: 'MSNBC', 
        link: 'http://www.msnbc.com'
    }]
}
```

The other issue is the value assigned to `a` is not a key of `dataThirdSelect`:

```
$('#test2').on('change', function() {
    var a = $(this).val();
    if (a !== '') {
        for (var i = 0; i < dataThirdSelect[a].length; i++) {
            $('#test3').append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value", dataThirdSelect[a][i])
                .text(dataThirdSelect[a][i]));
        }
    }
});
```

Following the previously constructed options, I think you'll want to change the `Test1`, and `Test2` keys:

```
var dataThirdSelect = {
    Test1: ['C', 'D'],
    Test2: ['G', 'H']
}
```

to

```
var dataThirdSelect = {
    A : ['C', 'D'],
    B : ['G', 'H'],
    E : ['C', 'D'], //Fill these in with the desired values.
    F : ['G', 'H']
}
```

hopefully, that gets you on the right track.

[Edit] To help answer your comment:
Based on your current design I might recommend assigning the selected values to a dictionary on each change event. For example:

```
var selectedOptions = {};

$('#test2').on('change', function() {
    var a = $(this).val();
    selectedOptions['test2'] = a
    //...
}
```

Then on submit you can check those values like so:

```
Object.keys(selectedOptions).forEach((option) => {
    //Do something with each option using selectedOptions[option]
    console.log(selectedOptions[option]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, with those modifications I was able to execute the 3rd & 4th drop down lists. One last question, for the 2nd drop down if I have the same value for Test1 & Test2, lets say 'A' value for both, how would I differentiate between the two values in the 3rd drop down?

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your comment. Please mark it as correct if I've answered the original question.